# JSP/Servlet : How to Read an image via URL and render it on a JSP page (image URL is not public)

Tags: java, image, jsp

what's the best approach to read an image via URL and render it on a JSP page?

so far, I've coded two JSP pages.

EDIT START:

```
 *Experimental: Obviously the ImageServ will be a servlet, not a jsp.
```

EDIT END:

```
index.jsp

<%page ....
<html>
......
<img src="ImageServ.jsp?url=http://serveripaddress/folder/image.jpg" />
.....


ImageServ.jsp
<%@page import="javax.imageio.ImageIO"%>
<%@page import="java.net.URL"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*, java.awt.*, java.awt.image.*,com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*" %>
<%
    try {
        String urlStr = "";
        if(request.getParameter("url") != null)
        {
            urlStr = request.getParameter("url");
            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            BufferedImage img = null;
            try{
                    img = ImageIO.read(url);
                    out.println(" READ SUCCESS" + "<br>");
            }catch(Exception e) {
                    out.println("READ ERROR "  + "<br>");
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
            }

            try {
                    response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(response.getOutputStream());
                    encoder.encode(img);
                 }catch(Exception ee) {
                            response.setContentType("text/html");
                            out.println("ENCODING ERROR "  + "<br>");
                            ee.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
            }
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(out));
    }
%>
```

But this  doesn't seem to be working:
all the time i see this error:

```
READ SUCCESS
ENCODING ERROR
java.io.IOException: reading encoded JPEG Stream 
    at sun.awt.image.codec.JPEGImageEncoderImpl.writeJPEGStream(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.image.codec.JPEGImageEncoderImpl.encode(JPEGImageEncoderImpl.java:476)
    at sun.awt.image.codec.JPEGImageEncoderImpl.encode(JPEGImageEncoderImpl.java:228)
```

Any ideas on how to get this working???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image data is already encoded so you can simply write it: `ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", response.getOutputStream());`. You don't need to (and can't) use `JPEGImageEncoder`.

Comment: didnt work, as img is of type BufferedImage ; got an error that says /ImageServ.jsp:57: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method write(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)
location: class java.io.OutputStream
    o.write(img);

Comment: Thanks! but still trying to find a way to write the BufferedImage successfully to jsp outputstream.

Comment: @Satish: so use `ImageIO.write(img, "jpeg", response.getOutputStream());`

Comment: java.io.CharConversionException: illegal utf8 encoding at 0xd8
 at com.caucho.vfs.i18n.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:145)
 at com.caucho.server.http.ToCharResponseStream.write(ToCharResponseStream.java:297)
 at com.caucho.server.http.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:70)
 at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:58)

Comment: hmm looks like something else going on. ImageIO should work. but not sure, why my app server is throwing the CharConversionException.

Comment: @Satish: what kind of URL is it? maybe you can simply copy stream (IOUtils) to response.getOutputStream() ?

Comment: @Satish let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1934/discussion-between-zacheusz-and-satish)

Comment: maybe you deleted this line: `response.setContentType("image/jpeg");` ?

Answer (score 0):

Classic question.  Here's an example: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetImage.html

Also, don't do all that coding in a JSP - keep that for front-end rendering coding only; do the Java coding in a backend class.

Answer (score 0):

Terrible and awful code. NEVER EVER write controller logic in a JSP that's why I have JSP to the guts. You cannot write binary data to a JSP output stream. The stream has already been initialized for text output. Put your logic in a servlet and pipe the input stream to the response output stream with Commons IO. This will work. If you still insist on that crappy solution, you will need to write a filter which completely wraps the response and serves binary data instead. See [this](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/export_filter.html) for reference and examine its code. Good luck.

Edit:

```
doGet(...) {
  response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
  String url = request.getParameter("url");
  ...
  InputStream is = ....getInputStream();
  IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
  // cleanup
  } // done
```

This is how I pipe PDF from local disk but there is no difference to serving from a URL.

Comment: This was an experimental code!! and refreshing a JSP is easy, make a change and page reload, you have changes up and running. For some reason it's a pain in the neck thing getting servlet to refresh, as my eclipse asks for "Publish"

Comment: Even though, never get accustomed to such an approach.
See above for a cheap servlet approach.

Comment: any examples on piping input stream with commons io ?